# output in json form

Tags: bash, json

The following command gives memory usage into normal form.

```
awk '/^Mem/ {printf("%u%%", 100*$3/$2);}' <(free -m)
```

I want to get it in valid json form.

**Desire output:**
Example:

```
{"Memory":"80"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this, read info from proc fs, and use bc to calculate:

```
#!/bin/bash
tot=$(awk '{ if (/MemTotal:/) {print $2} }' </proc/meminfo)
free=$(awk '{ if (/MemFree:/) {print $2} }' </proc/meminfo)
pers=$(echo "scale=0; 100 - 100 * $free / $tot" | bc)
echo '{"Memory":"'$pers'"}'
```

Comment: Note that your formula needs minor adjustment. The question used “100 * used / total”, while you use “100 * free / total”.

Answer (score 2):

If using `awk` is not mandatory, I prefer `ruby` for JSON formatting. Much longer that a bare `awk` script, but easier to extend it later:

```
ruby -rjson -nae 'BEGIN{j={}};j["Memory"]="#{(100*$F[2].to_f/$F[1].to_f).to_i}%"if/^Mem/;END{puts j.to_json}' <(free -m)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a command-line tool called `jc`. It can convert the output of many command line tools to JSON.

```
$ jc free | jq
[
  {
    "type": "Mem",
    "total": 3861332,
    "used": 338196,
    "free": 2840616,
    "shared": 11848,
    "buff_cache": 682520,
    "available": 3222232
  },
  {
    "type": "Swap",
    "total": 2097148,
    "used": 0,
    "free": 2097148
  }
]
```

https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc

Answer (score 1):

Using [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) to create a single JSON object with a `Memory` key and the percentage of memory used, as given by `free` and calculated by `awk`:

```bsh
jo Memory="$(free -m| awk '/^Mem:/ { printf "%u%%\n", 100*$3/$2 }')"
```

Note that the unit used in the output of `free` is unimportant.

Example output:

```json
{"Memory":"5%"}
```

The equivalent thing, but using `jq`:

```bsh
jq -nc --arg memused "$(free | awk '/^Mem:/ { printf "%u%%\n", 100*$3/$2 }')" '{ Memory: $memused }'
```

Answer (score 0):

With an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) one-liner :

```
awk '$1=="MemTotal:"{t=$2} $1=="MemFree:"{f=$2}END{printf "{\042Memory\042:\042%s\042}\n",  int(100 - 100 * f / t)}' /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
free -h | jq -R -s '
[
  split("\n") |
  .[] |
  if test("^Mem") then
    gsub(" +"; " ") | split(" ") | {totalmem: .[1], used: .[2], free: .[3], shared: .[4], cached: .[5], available: .[6]}
  else
    empty
  end
]'
```